# Anyone know what these white grubs are?

Tags: identification, soil, grubs

[image]

I have found loads of them in the soil in the large planter I have herbs in

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: Possibly the first or second stage pupa of some  sort - there should be a third stage to come. Could be some  sort of beetle or fly, not sure which